# UILocalNotification custom soundName not playing

Tags: ios, swift

I have tried every conceivable way to play a custom sound name
(formatted on mac to aiff, wav, formatted with online tool, used old sound that used to work, moved file, renamed file, made sure song is under 30 seconds, cleaned project, deleted app, restarted iPhone, deleted derivedData.

Basically everything, but it just does not work. I am guessing it must be a bug.  I have tried for 2-3 days now and read all the SO questions and forums - no luck.

So I am giving up and just want to play a ringtone, ideally one 29 seconds long.
How can I do that?  Are there any ringtones/system sounds other than UILocalNotificationDefaultSoundName ?

Any help would be very much appreciated !

```
func pushRegistry(registry: PKPushRegistry, didReceiveIncomingPushWithPayload payload: PKPushPayload, forType type: String) {
    print("\n\n##  DID RECEIVE NOTIFICATION ## \n\n")

    let data = payload.dictionaryPayload

    if let type = data["type"] as? String {
        if type == "MESSAGE_NOTE" {
            print("Notification is Message")
            let notification = UILocalNotification()
            notification.alertTitle = "App message"
            notification.soundName =  UILocalNotificationDefaultSoundName
            notification.userInfo = ["type":type]
            notification.alertBody = "New message"
            notification.alertAction = "Accept"
            UIApplication.sharedApplication().applicationIconBadgeNumber += 1
            UIApplication.sharedApplication().presentLocalNotificationNow(notification)

        } else if type == "INCOMING_CALL" {
            print("Notification is incoming call")
            let notification = UILocalNotification()
            notification.alertTitle = "App call"
            notification.soundName =  "Simple_ring_tone_29s.aiff"
            notification.userInfo = ["type":type]
            notification.alertBody = "Incoming call"
            notification.alertAction = "Accept"
            UIApplication.sharedApplication().applicationIconBadgeNumber += 1
            UIApplication.sharedApplication().presentLocalNotificationNow(notification)
        }
    }
}
```

Notification settings is registered in another VC

```
    let notificationSettings: UIUserNotificationSettings! = UIApplication.sharedApplication().currentUserNotificationSettings()

    if !notificationSettings.types.contains([.Badge, .Sound, .Alert])  {
        let notificationTypes: UIUserNotificationType = [.Badge, .Sound, .Alert]
        let notificationSettings = UIUserNotificationSettings(forTypes: notificationTypes, categories: nil)
        UIApplication.sharedApplication().registerUserNotificationSettings(notificationSettings)
```

In didFinishLaunchingWithOptions

```
    voipRegistry = PKPushRegistry(queue: dispatch_get_main_queue())
    voipRegistry.delegate = self
    voipRegistry.desiredPushTypes = Set([PKPushTypeVoIP])
```

Comment: How you register your notification settings for notification sound I n appDelegate

Comment: @joe Added info in question.  Is that what you were wondering about ?

Comment: 1. Does it play for default sound ? 2. Are your playing the sound from web or local ? 3. Did you register in didfinishlaunch method ?@KML

Comment: @jamshed-alam 1) Yes, 2) the soundfile ("Simple_ring_tone_29s.aiff") is stored locally in the main bundle 3) What do you mean register ?

Comment: What's your simulator iOS version ?

Comment: @jamshed-alam I dont use simulator

Comment: whatever, device iOS ?

Comment: @jamshed-alam Deploy target 9.3, device iOS 10.0.2, Swift 2.3

Answer (score 0):

This problem is Fixed from iOS 10.1 beta 2.

https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/49512

Comment: First I wish I had seen that thread 3 days ago, how did you find it ?
Second, how do you interpret it?  Will it work for real users that download from app store? Or is it a problem for everyone ?

Comment: I am guessing it is only a problem for developers, as our current app in app store plays the correct sound for iOS 10.0.2, although I have done a few changes since then.

Comment: May be you are right . Check it with update iOS version on device or simulator.